# Will having many, many UserSettings have a noticeable impact on performance?

Tags: c#

Basically, the way that I'm doing something requires me to have 84+ UserSettings in C#. It's just the nature of the task (don't worry, I'm still in education and it's never actually going to be used) that requires me to do so.

The question that I wish to ask is this: will having so many settings noticeably impact the performance of my application? Each one of them will be used over a year, but only seven or so will be used in one month. At the start of the year (i.e if the application is started on the 1st of January and has not been started on that day previously), it will clear these 84 values.

The demand of the task is that I have some sort of system within an existing program to save costs incurred within a month - and can do this for the past twelve months. I would save all of these costs in an external file, but since I'm using C# - it raises questions when there is a better alternative. I just want to know if this is feasible. Settings, if they had no observable impact, would be better as they:

- can't accidentally be deleted
- are harder to modify, but I recognize that they still can be, but the thing is that it is significantly harder (and this is an important point when dealing with costs)
- are easier to deal with than files, as they shouldn't require as many catch statements
- could potentially be faster to access

I know that I probably wouldn't lose any marks for rolling with a text file, but using settings would make my life easier. So is there any impact?

Comment: serializing a settings class of values is insanely simple; performance issues are beside the point, if you need them, you need them.

Comment: What makes you think settings can't accidentally be deleted?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot I guess I should say that they would be harder to accidentally delete. I believe that they're stored in Roaming data or something like that, or at least in a file that the user wouldn't know about. I'll likely be going with a zipped approach to distributing the program, versus an installer, as I don't have time to sort all of that out and it's just a simple cut-and-paste job, and the application doesn't require any special permissions or options. In that sense, having a bunch of text files which may accidentally failed to be copied by the user is worse than having settings.

Comment: Write a test application and give it a try. Only you know what a _noticeable_ impact on performance will be in your environment with your data.

Comment: I've just used the 84 settings and there does not seem to be an impact on performance.

It is not saving however, so I'll need to look into that